# Scrolling to particular <p> inside a <div> with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am writing a simple chat app that consists of scrollable div containing chat messages (each chat message is a paragraph < p>chatmessage< /p>). Upon loading a page div displays 10 most recent messages. What I want to achieve is if I scroll the chat div up, it would prepend 10 previous messages and autoscroll it so the last prepended message would appear on top of the div window.

HTML looks like this just to get the idea:

```
            <div id="chatscrollbox" >
                <div id="chatcontent" >
                    <p>10</p>
                    <p>9</p>
                    <p>8</p>
                    <p>7</p>
                    <p>6</p>
                    <p>5</p>
                    <p>4</p>
                    <p>3</p>
                    <p>2</p>
                    <p>1</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Scrolling the div up, it would prepend messages from 11-20, the content reading from the top to bottom would look now: 20,19,18...3,2,1.

Everything works, except I do not know how to scroll the div with jquery to particular

element inside it (no names, no classe). Is there in jquery something like: scroll to X-th

element inside div? Or how to achieve it if there isn't such command? In my example I would like to scroll to 11th element. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should add anchor links insinde your `<p>` ?

Comment: script that fills in a portion doesn't know nothing about what content there already is in the div, I would rather prefer to scroll to particular <p> element knowing its number (element number like index in array or something)

Answer (score 1):

Since your `p` tags are direct descendants of `<div id="chatcontent" >`, you can create an array of `p`'s like this:

```
let nthP = $("#chatcontent").children("p");
```

You could also just get the `p` you're looking for directly with a selector:

```
let myP = $("#chatcontent").find("p:eq(60)");
```

Once you have the paragraph that you want, simply scroll to it.

```
 $('html, body').animate({
      // 60 represents the index of the p you want. Change it...
      // Or use a more specific selector to only grab the one you want (see above)
      scrollTop: $(nthP[60]).offset().top
 }, 2000);
```

Here's a working demo:

```js
let nthP = $("#chatcontent").children("p");
$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $(nthP[60]).offset().top
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chatscrollbox">
  <div id="chatcontent">
    <p>10</p>
    <p>9</p>
    <p>8</p>
    <p>7</p>
    <p>6</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>10</p>
    <p>9</p>
    <p>8</p>
    <p>7</p>
    <p>6</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>10</p>
    <p>9</p>
    <p>8</p>
    <p>7</p>
    <p>6</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>10</p>
    <p>9</p>
    <p>8</p>
    <p>7</p>
    <p>6</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>10</p>
    <p>9</p>
    <p>8</p>
    <p>7</p>
    <p>6</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>10</p>
    <p>9</p>
    <p>8</p>
    <p>7</p>
    <p>6</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>10</p>
    <p>9</p>
    <p>8</p>
    <p>7</p>
    <p>6</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>1</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

To only scroll an overflowed div, without animation, simply call `scrollTop` on the div:

```
$("#chatcontent").scrollTop($(myP).offset().top);
```

Here's [a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ov68u5o3/8/) of this example.

Comment: how would scrolling an overflow hidden div look like? I dont want to scroll the whole page.. only inside a div and without animate. Shouldnt something like this work: $('#chatcontent').scrollTop = something?

Comment: @Maris, see edit. FYI, unless it's done on page load (and sometimes even then), instant scrolling usually makes for a confusing user experience.

Comment: After several iterations offset starts to become lower than 1, like 0.2, 0.3 which translates into not scrolling to right position. Any ideas?

Comment: @Maris, without seeing the code and how you're actually using it, no. It seems like a new question is in order as the above answers your original question (how to scroll to a specific location). Ping me when you post it and I'll take a look.

Comment: The problem here I think is dynamically prepended additional items, since the more times you prepend the less top 10's offset value value becomes and even goes negative.

Comment: Just an idea - maybe $(myP).offset().top doesn't give a position inside a #chatcontent div but somewhat global ?

Comment: And yes, as soon as I change $("#chatcontent").scrollTop($(myP).offset().top); to $("#chatcontent").scrollTop($(myP).position().top); everything starts to work

Answer (score -1):

You can use the hash part of the location to navigate to elements of the page that have ids.

I'm using setTimeout just for a demonstration of the scrolling-to.

```js
setTimeout(function(){window.location.hash = "p1";}, 3000);
```

```html
<div id="chatscrollbox" >
    <div id="chatcontent" >
        <p id="p10">10</p>
        <p id="p9">9</p>
        <p id="p8">8</p>
        <p id="p7">7</p>
        <p id="p6">6</p>
        <p id="p5">5</p>
        <p id="p4">4</p>
        <p id="p3">3</p>
        <p id="p2">2</p>
        <p id="p1">1</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nope, this wont work, script that gives me a portion wont know what ids there already are and how many.. so this approach is not working for me! I have to rely purely on knowing the index number of each <p> like an element of an array,.. then i can simply compare how many <p> there were, and how many were added, calculate the difference and that's the element i want to scroll to

Comment: Where did the id's come from? You can't just change the markup to suite your approach.

Comment: Of course i can change the Markup, in general.  If it is a "no" for the change, it has to be in the question.

Comment: @Adder, the OP said that there are no names, classes, etc. in the `p` tags, that's why they didn't know how to select them. I think it's safe to assume that if the `p`'s had IDs, the question wouldn't have been asked. In fact, the OP specifically asks how to do it by index.

Comment: Well I am not sure anymore but maybe that part was not in the question when I answered it.